# After installation windows 10, touchpad gestures stopped working

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, acer-aspire

Bought an Acer Aspire 5 A515-51G with endless OS and decided to install windows 10. As a aftermath - gestures on my touchpad stopped works.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Acer support answered that I should switch touchpad from basic to advanced in BIOS.
So that helps, now have all gestures that I expected.